# How to Install ASP.NET core scanner for aws linux 2

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

## Starting: Run Code Analysis

Task         : Run Code Analysis
Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
Version      : 5.17.2
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : Version: 5.17.2. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

## [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)

D:\a_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\5.17.2\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.14
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
Calling the TFS Processor executable...
Attempting to locate the CodeCoverage.exe tool...
Attempting to locate the CodeCoverage.exe tool using setup configuration...
Code coverage command line tool: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe
Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...
Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...
Looking for TRX files in: D:\a\1\TestResults
No test results files found
Did not find any binary coverage files in the expected location.
Falling back on locating coverage files in the agent temp directory.
Searching for coverage files in D:\a_temp
No coverage files found in the agent temp directory.
Coverage report conversion completed successfully.
The TFS Processor has finished
Calling the SonarScanner CLI...
##[error]Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command line on your Linux machine to install the latest version of SonarScanner for .NET Core.

```bash
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
```

For more details, see "[**SonarScanner for .NET**](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/)". As the statement in this documentation, before executing this command line, ensure you have walked through the [**Prerequisites**](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/#prerequisites) steps. Then do the [**Installation**](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/#iInstallation) steps.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing it in a windows VM got it right, But in Linux no luck  'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command also installed .Net code scanner still the same error !